# Android Token save from json api

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

i need help in storing acces_token and token_type from json object data so i can make the user sesion work ,
every time user logs in, a new token is asigned , i want my acctivity to sync with the token, and when the token dies(expires)take user back to Login, so far i did only sesion management by some string from "String  _token_type= "token_type";" and that is a bad result so far ,also i need to somehow post the token and token type to other activity to parse JsonObject by user token,i'm really sorry for my bad english , and maybe for a dumb question ,i'm really desperate i'm tryng to figure it out for 3 days

**Json Response when logged**

```
code: 200
error: false
message: "Ok"
data: {
access_token: "585e35343139636330653062613965827"
expires_in: 86400
token_type: "Bearer"
}
```

**Code**

```
package baymd.baymdalpha;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import baymd.baymdalpha.librarys.JSONParser;


public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {



private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://example.com/api/auth";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "code";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String TAG_DATA="data";
private static final String TAG_TOKEN_TYPE="token_type";
private static final String TAG_TOKEN="access_token";
JSONArray data = null;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private EditText user, pass;
private Button mSubmit;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private String token,token_type;


//Shared preff vars
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String _token = "access_token";
public static final String  _token_type= "token_type";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPass);


    mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Shared Prefs Thing


}
protected void onResume(){
    sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(sharedpreferences.contains(_token)){

        Log.d("LOL",_token);

        if(sharedpreferences.contains(_token_type)){
            Intent i=new Intent(this,BayTab.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new AttemptLogin().execute();


}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            Log.d("request", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 200) {
                JSONObject c=json.getJSONObject(TAG_DATA);

               SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedpreferences.edit();

                token=c.getString(TAG_TOKEN);
                Log.d("TOKENS",token);
                 token_type=c.getString(TAG_TOKEN_TYPE);
                Log.d("TOKENS",token_type);

                String u = token;
                String p = token_type;
                editor.putString(_token,u);
                editor.putString(_token_type,p);
                Log.d("RESPONSEFROMSHARED.....",_token+" "+u+ "\n"+_token_type+" "+p);

                editor.commit();


                Log.d("Login Successeful", json.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, BayTab.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (s != null) {

            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Google Gson for this.

First create two model classes, one for Session Response and another for the data object. Do as follows:
1. Create the model. Make sure that each class mimics the response keys EXACTLY. Also, make sure that each class has a default constructor as well.

```
public class SessionResponse {

  int code;
  String error, message;
  Data data;

  public SessionResponse(){}

  public int getCode() {
      return code;
  }

  public void setCode(int code) {
      this.code = code;
  }

  public String getError() {
      return error;
  }

  public void setError(String error) {
      this.error = error;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
      return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
      this.message = message;
  }

  public Data getData() {
      return data;
  }

  public void setData(Data data) {
      this.data = data;
  }
}

public class Data {

    String access_token, token_type;
    int expires_in;

    public Data(){}

    public String getAccess_token() {
        return access_token;
    }

    public void setAccess_token(String access_token) {
        this.access_token = access_token;
    }

    public String getToken_type() {
        return token_type;
    }

    public void setToken_type(String token_type) {
        this.token_type = token_type;
    }

    public int getExpires_in() {
        return expires_in;
    }

    public void setExpires_in(int expires_in) {
        this.expires_in = expires_in;
    }

}
```

Then use the Google Gson support library to convert the Json to an object. You can then store it to Shared Preferences and get it from any activity. Or even pass it to an activity by string via Intent.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

//get the class from JSON
SessionResponse response = gson.fromJson(jsonResponseString, SessionResponse.class);

//convert to String
String jsonResponse = gson.toJson(response);
```

I hope this is a good start!